# OpenXML find frozen panes

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I'm tyring to locate any frozen panes in an excel document.  Is this possible with OpenXML?  I know you can create a frozen pane with OpenXML but I want to know if I can find out if there exist a frozen pane?

Comment: If I get the right answer I accept it.  I'm using OpenXML.

Comment: Do you want to do anything specific after you find frozen panes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pane pane = new Pane()
{
    State = PaneStateValues.Frozen
};
```

This instantiates a new Pane with the state of frozen.
If you have a collection of Panes like so:

```
List<Pane> myPanes = new List<Pane>(); 
panes.Add(//pane//);
```

Loop through all the panes and see if they're frozen

```
foreach (var pane in myPanes)
{
    if (pane.State == PaneStateValues.Frozen)
    {
         //Do something with pane
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i get a list of the panes if I'm not the one adding them?

Comment: Hmm never tried that but I think its a worksheet object descendants `worksheet.Descendants<Cell>();`

Comment: @dcinadr gah Replace `Cell` with `Pane` miss typed when looking at the refrence